# How to use multiple array elements with 'for' in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, leaflet

I am trying to pass multiple values from an array into a for statement, it is only working on the last value at the moment. The result is that it colours the country Brazil rather than both Brazil **and** United States of America. How can I pass multiple values into the function without running it multiple times?
Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J4643/

Here is the JS:

```
var colourCountries = ["United States of America","Brazil"];
var mapboxTiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/alexplummer.him2149i/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');
var map = L.map('map')
.addLayer(mapboxTiles)
.setView([30, 0], 3);
function style(feature) {
for (var i=1; i<= colourCountries.length; i++) {
 if (colourCountries[i] == feature.properties.name) {
   return {
   weight: 2,
   opacity: 1,
   color: 'white',
   dashArray: '3',
   fillOpacity: 0.3,
   fillColor: '#ff0000'
 };
 } 
     else {
   return {
   weight: 1,
   opacity: 1,
   color: '#32B3EF',
   fillOpacity: 1,
   fillColor: '#F3F4E8'
 };
 }
}
}       
var geojson, thisCountry;
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {}
geojson = L.geoJson(countryData, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
    style: style
}).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 errors. Array indexes start with 0 not 1. Also the way it was written, the loop would always return on the first lap. This works:

```
function style(feature) {
  for (var i=0; i < colourCountries.length; i++) {
    if (colourCountries[i] == feature.properties.name) {
      return {
        weight: 2,
        opacity: 1,
        color: 'white',
        dashArray: '3',
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        fillColor: '#ff0000'
      };
    }
  }

  return {
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    color: '#32B3EF',
    fillOpacity: 1,
    fillColor: '#F3F4E8'
  };
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sabof/Pc8j7/)**

Alternatively:

```
function style(feature) {
  var style1 = {
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 1,
    color: 'white',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.3,
    fillColor: '#ff0000'
  };
  var style2 = {
    weight: 1,
    opacity: 1,
    color: '#32B3EF',
    fillOpacity: 1,
    fillColor: '#F3F4E8'
  };

  if ( colourCountries.indexOf(feature.properties.name) !== -1) {
    return style1;
  } 
  return style2;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for highlighting the mistakes as well!